# Adding a custom font in PHPSpreadhseet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet, maatwebsite-excel

I am generating an excel file as report using PHP spreadsheet. I need the report in excel however the font should be "Nikosh"(Bangla Font). Excel is using the font "Calibri" by default.
If I pass "Nikosh" as Font name in style array, Excel cant format the text accordingly. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try this line `$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');`

Comment: @Joseph What if i want to pass "Nikosh" as parameter in setName() ?  As it is not listed in Phpspreadsheet/shared/Font.php how to add this ?

Comment: it looks that this package didn't support another font